# Hibernate mapping suggestion for three tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring mvc with hibernate with annotation,
i have table structure like this where 1 module can have multiple permissions

```
permissions table [perm_id, perm_name, perm_type_id, perm_created_by, perm_created_date, perm_modified_date, perm_status]
module_permissions table [mp_id, mp_mod_id, mp_perm_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_modified_date, mp_status]
modules table [mod_id, mod_name, mod_icon, mod_created_date, mod_modified_date, mod_status]
```

All the permissions are created first.

so every time user creates a new module, permissions are assigned to that module.

here, simplest way is to use for loop for every permission and make entry in mapping table with all that required columns in mapping table.

But i guess there are some better ways like use onetomany mapping or else 
    can any one suggest me which mapping can be used here??

I have tried this mapping as follw in modules entity

```
@Transient
private List<Long> permissions;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="mp_mod_id")
private Set<ModulePermissionMpg> modulePermissionMpg;
//getter and setter
```

And my module_permission_mapping have follwing mapping

```
@ManyToOne
private ModuleMst moduleMst;
```

and this is working fineyou can see here

```
Hibernate: insert into a_modules (mod_created_date, mod_icon, mod_modified_date, mod_name, mod_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into a_module_permissions (moduleMst_mod_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_mod_id, mp_modified_date, mp_perm_id, mp_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into a_module_permissions (moduleMst_mod_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_mod_id, mp_modified_date, mp_perm_id, mp_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into a_module_permissions (moduleMst_mod_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_mod_id, mp_modified_date, mp_perm_id, mp_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update a_module_permissions set mp_mod_id=? where mp_id=?
Hibernate: update a_module_permissions set mp_mod_id=? where mp_id=?
Hibernate: update a_module_permissions set mp_mod_id=? where mp_id=?
```

so now my question is , how can I delete all mapped enties from mapping table when I delete a single module?

Comment: I think it's unlikely that this question will be answered in its current state. Please include some evidence that you've tried to implement associations between these entities and then tell us what problems you're encountering.

Comment: Just delete the module. And thanks to `cascade=CascadeType.ALL`, its associated ModulePermissionMpg instances will also be deleted. Your code is extremaly hard to read due to all the noise brought by the useless and meaningless prefixes and suffixes used everywhere. Drop the perm_, mp_ and mod_ prefixes in column names, and the Mpg and Mst suffixes in class and variable names.

Comment: @JBNizet  I know that prefix and suffixes are very bad but I have given this table structre and I cant change this, and there is another problem , everytime I insers a new module entry , I gets a column named "moduleMst_mod_id" I dont form where it gets created filld with a NULL in mapping table